No Studio Controls in latest Ubuntu Studio
I recently updated my OS to 24.04 Ubuntu Studio. I noticed that studio controls is absent. My DAW runs using JACK. I used to use Studio Controls to specify the USB device I am using etc. Now I am at a bit of a loss as to how to get it working on the new OS. Is there some alternative way of running this DAW on the new OS?
Any help much appreciated.
Best Wishes
Matt Hammond
